# How to detect damages in car tyres using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

I want to detect damages in car tyres , how can i achieve this using tensorflow , i'm working in python and i will have users uploading images of tyres which will be processed individually

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on object detection using tensorflow. 
You can try there object detection api
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection
the above link which is the tensorflow object detection api it has a brief intro on about how to install and get started.

You can start with Fast-Rcnn its a robust object detection and can work for your usecase.But you will need a huge amount of data . If you have less data you can always use data-augmentation tech to increase it

Once you have trained the model, you can use the Flask http://flask.pocoo.org/
to build a server where you can define the api's for the user to make request and you can then run inference on the images using you trained model and give back the response

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to help you..Something similar done for cars...

https://github.com/neokt/car-damage-detective